# JSON not valid EOF (Python)

Tags: python, json

I am trying to build up a JSON using the following code but jsonlint says it's not valid, ending with EOF error.
The error is that I have to separate the output but my goal is to have a single JSON file.

Here is the code I am using:

```
t = 0
p = []
nome_b = (bollist[0])
p_causale = (causalestr) #contains a string

for item in jsonlist:
    predizione = (jsonlist[t])

    bollettini = {'Nome bollettino': str(nome_b)}
    causale = {'Stringa Causale': str(p_causale)}
    numero = {'Numero': str(predizione)}

    t += 1
    p.append([bollettini]+[causale]+[numero])

if not y: 
    jsontxt = ('Not found')
else:
    #jsontxt = ([bollettini],[causale],[numero])
    jsontxt = (p)

with open((TXT.txt'), 'a', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    json.dump(jsontxt, outfile)
```

And this is the output:

```
[[{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "026554891"}, {"Numero": "0[(96.48 % n: 0) (3.37 % n: 9) (0.06 % n: 4)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "026554891"}, {"Numero": "2[(36.17 % n: 2) (25.01 % n: 0) (18.48 % n: 9)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "026554891"}, {"Numero": "6[(99.9 % n: 6) (0.09 % n: 4) (0.0 % n: 9)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "026554891"}, {"Numero": "5[(99.99 % n: 5) (0.0 % n: 9) (0.0 % n: 8)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "026554891"}, {"Numero": "5[(99.98 % n: 5) (0.01 % n: 3) (0.0 % n: 9)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "026554891"}, {"Numero": "4[(84.76 % n: 4) (7.63 % n: 0) (2.08 % n: 6)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "026554891"}, {"Numero": "8[(89.88 % n: 8) (8.87 % n: 9) (1.11 % n: 5)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "026554891"}, {"Numero": "9[(84.29 % n: 9) (8.23 % n: 8) (6.79 % n: 0)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "026554891"}, {"Numero": "1[(99.99 % n: 1) (0.0 % n: 9) (0.0 % n: 8)]"}]][[{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "45602931566"}, {"Numero": "4[(80.03 % n: 4) (18.44 % n: 1) (0.69 % n: 3)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "45602931566"}, {"Numero": "5[(99.99 % n: 5) (0.0 % n: 9) (0.0 % n: 8)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "45602931566"}, {"Numero": "6[(99.91 % n: 6) (0.04 % n: 0) (0.03 % n: 4)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "45602931566"}, {"Numero": "0[(99.99 % n: 0) (0.0 % n: 9) (0.0 % n: 8)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "45602931566"}, {"Numero": "2[(99.86 % n: 2) (0.12 % n: 8) (0.01 % n: 3)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "45602931566"}, {"Numero": "9[(99.07 % n: 9) (0.83 % n: 8) (0.04 % n: 5)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "45602931566"}, {"Numero": "3[(99.99 % n: 3) (0.0 % n: 9) (0.0 % n: 8)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "45602931566"}, {"Numero": "1[(50.74 % n: 1) (40.73 % n: 7) (5.93 % n: 5)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "45602931566"}, {"Numero": "5[(36.81 % n: 5) (29.07 % n: 8) (16.1 % n: 6)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "45602931566"}, {"Numero": "6[(98.46 % n: 6) (0.66 % n: 4) (0.64 % n: 2)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "45602931566"}, {"Numero": "6[(69.49 % n: 6) (20.06 % n: 1) (6.35 % n: 8)]"}]][[{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "5711587681155"}, {"Numero": "5[(60.71 % n: 5) (29.06 % n: 8) (8.77 % n: 7)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "5711587681155"}, {"Numero": "7[(85.45 % n: 7) (8.71 % n: 9) (1.92 % n: 0)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "5711587681155"}, {"Numero": "1[(99.99 % n: 1) (0.0 % n: 9) (0.0 % n: 8)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "5711587681155"}, {"Numero": "1[(99.18 % n: 1) (0.42 % n: 2) (0.39 % n: 4)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "5711587681155"}, {"Numero": "5[(99.99 % n: 5) (0.0 % n: 9) (0.0 % n: 8)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "5711587681155"}, {"Numero": "8[(99.98 % n: 8) (0.01 % n: 2) (0.0 % n: 9)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "5711587681155"}, {"Numero": "7[(99.8 % n: 7) (0.12 % n: 3) (0.04 % n: 4)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "5711587681155"}, {"Numero": "6[(99.99 % n: 6) (0.0 % n: 9) (0.0 % n: 8)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "5711587681155"}, {"Numero": "8[(59.18 % n: 8) (32.39 % n: 2) (6.08 % n: 6)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "5711587681155"}, {"Numero": "1[(99.99 % n: 1) (0.0 % n: 9) (0.0 % n: 8)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "5711587681155"}, {"Numero": "1[(95.61 % n: 1) (3.78 % n: 2) (0.48 % n: 8)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "5711587681155"}, {"Numero": "5[(99.99 % n: 5) (0.0 % n: 9) (0.0 % n: 8)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "5711587681155"}, {"Numero": "5[(99.85 % n: 5) (0.14 % n: 8) (0.0 % n: 9)]"}]][[{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "158775853"}, {"Numero": "1[(75.32 % n: 1) (24.4 % n: 2) (0.26 % n: 4)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "158775853"}, {"Numero": "5[(99.99 % n: 5) (0.0 % n: 9) (0.0 % n: 8)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "158775853"}, {"Numero": "8[(99.97 % n: 8) (0.01 % n: 2) (0.0 % n: 9)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "158775853"}, {"Numero": "7[(99.99 % n: 7) (0.0 % n: 9) (0.0 % n: 8)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "158775853"}, {"Numero": "7[(64.8 % n: 7) (35.17 % n: 2) (0.0 % n: 9)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "158775853"}, {"Numero": "5[(99.99 % n: 5) (0.0 % n: 9) (0.0 % n: 8)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "158775853"}, {"Numero": "8[(97.63 % n: 8) (1.19 % n: 3) (1.14 % n: 9)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "158775853"}, {"Numero": "5[(80.64 % n: 5) (18.03 % n: 3) (0.81 % n: 7)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "158775853"}, {"Numero": "3[(99.99 % n: 3) (0.0 % n: 9) (0.0 % n: 8)]"}]][[{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "1411588337082"}, {"Numero": "1[(99.99 % n: 1) (0.0 % n: 9) (0.0 % n: 8)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "1411588337082"}, {"Numero": "4[(80.31 % n: 4) (10.32 % n: 1) (5.49 % n: 2)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "1411588337082"}, {"Numero": "1[(99.43 % n: 1) (0.31 % n: 2) (0.22 % n: 7)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "1411588337082"}, {"Numero": "1[(92.47 % n: 1) (4.77 % n: 4) (2.64 % n: 6)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "1411588337082"}, {"Numero": "5[(99.99 % n: 5) (0.0 % n: 9) (0.0 % n: 8)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "1411588337082"}, {"Numero": "8[(99.42 % n: 8) (0.56 % n: 2) (0.01 % n: 3)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "1411588337082"}, {"Numero": "8[(99.99 % n: 8) (0.0 % n: 9) (0.0 % n: 7)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "1411588337082"}, {"Numero": "3[(98.3 % n: 3) (1.69 % n: 5) (0.0 % n: 9)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "1411588337082"}, {"Numero": "3[(99.99 % n: 3) (0.0 % n: 9) (0.0 % n: 8)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "1411588337082"}, {"Numero": "7[(98.05 % n: 7) (1.5 % n: 2) (0.42 % n: 4)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "1411588337082"}, {"Numero": "0[(80.66 % n: 0) (18.98 % n: 2) (0.23 % n: 1)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "1411588337082"}, {"Numero": "8[(31.61 % n: 8) (28.47 % n: 4) (23.53 % n: 6)]"}], [{"Nome bollettino": "BR_3_VE33491116420151103K000351FA.png"}, {"Stringa Causale": "1411588337082"}, {"Numero": "2[(66.61 % n: 2) (26.19 % n: 4) (4.39 % n: 8)]"}]]"Not Found"
```

If you try to [validate it](https://jsonlint.com/), it says it's not valid.
How can I fix this ?
Also, how can I make "Nome bollettino" as root for every other object ?
I mean, like this:

```
- Nome bollettino:
   - Stringa Causale:
      - Numero:
```

Comment: Why is it adding `"Not Found"` at the end?

Comment: If an object is empty, I added a string which says me that it was recognized but is...empty.

Comment: That's obviously not your real code, as `TXT.txt'` is missing `'` at the start. Show the real code.

Comment: Try to produce a smaller output with the same error.

Comment: @chepner, well, which kind of ? All outputs are the same like the one above..

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're adding separate JSON structures to your file, and that's fine - that's a [*JSON line*](http://jsonlines.org/) file. However, `json.dump` doesn't automatically add newline delimiters after your data. You'll have to do it yourself.

```
with open(...) as outfile:
    json.dump(jsontxt, outfile)
    outfile.write('\n')
```

When validating your JSON, validate each line separately.

---

If you want to merge your JSONs into one, you'd accumulate everything in a loop and dump at the end. It'd be something like this:

```
data = []
for item in jsonList:
    ... # do something
    data.append(newItem) # newItem is your final json sub-structure

with open(..., 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Comment: That exact oufile there is in the code (commented) but I don't use it now because it don't do what I want. It won't be valid anyway, even with a newline..

Comment: @BlueTrack The point is to have each separate JSON be valid. If you are trying to merge them together, that's a whole different beast, which you should've mentioned.

Comment: Yes, that's it, I want to merge them. In fact, I did a test file which worked, a single valid json with multiple lines merged together..

Comment: @BlueTrack In that case, keep your structures in memory as a list, keep appending to the list, and do one final `json.dump`. That's how we usually do it.

Comment: Can you show me an example ? Where I have to "touch" the code ? All the above is all that I have about json in the whole script...

Comment: @BlueTrack Added representative example. Try and fit it into your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157910/discussion-between-bluetrack-and-cs).

Comment: @BlueTrack Not frequent enough to reply on chat. Just ping me in the comments!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand `newItem`. For example, in my code, it would like to use `json.dump(p, outfile)` instead of `json.dump(jsontxt, outfile)`, where "p" is `newItem` in yours...

Comment: @BlueTrack Then do `data.append(p)`?

Comment: I did it many times, the [result is the same](https://imgur.com/a/sUs80). With a [simple code](https://pastebin.com/x5RGvSC3) I made (just to do some testing), it works....

Comment: @BlueTrack Oh, sorry. In your case, `newItem` should be `[bollettini]+[causale]+[numero]`

Answer (score 1):

You opened the output file in append mode `'a'` which means you have two bits of json one after another and the result is not a single json value.

You cannot append json strings to a text file and expect the resulting file to be valid json. Open the file in `'w'` mode instead and you will overwrite the old value.

Comment: Perhaps overwriting isn't what OP wants?

Comment: @BlueTrack in that case post the actual code and say what it is you want to get as output: do you want a single json object in a file or a file with a lot of separate json objects?

Comment: It doens't matter if the code is full or not. Just immagine the above is in a for loop. My output should be as the above but JSON valid. I mean, if you look at the validator it says EOF on [ bracket. I don't want that...kinda hard to explain..